# Can I make git-svn aware of an SVN merge?

Tags: git, svn, git-svn, svn-merge

I use git to work on an existing SVN repository, which has now – conceptually – the following history:

```
A  ->  B  ->  C  ->  D  ->  E  ->  F  ->  G  ->  H  __
        \                                ➚             trunk
         ➘                              /
           M  ->  N  ->  O  ->  P  ->  Q  ___
                                              feature
```

Of course, *really* SVN doesn't have branches that one could merge, i.e. `G` is actually just a huge commit which reintegrates all the changes from `B..Q` into `trunk`.

So, right now, my git mirror looks just like this:

```
A  ->  B  ->  C  ->  D  ->  E  ->  F  ->  BMNOPQ  ->  H  __
        \                                                    trunk
         ➘                              
           M  ->  N  ->  O  ->  P  ->  Q  ___
                                              feature
```

Unlike svn though, git *has* proper merging, and could represent the history much clearer.

Is there some way to get the layout to look like it should in git – i.e., having the `feature` commits as explicit ancestors of `trunk` – while still allowing all new work (i.e. `dcommitting`) to be handled just like now?